# Help solving the functional equation $f(ax) = bf(x)$

Tags: logarithms, functional-equations

I was tinkering around with a small toy problem and ended up looking at the functional equation:
$$f(ax) = bf(x), \forall x \quad \text{where } a,b>1$$

I realize this is just a simple example of [Schröder's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation), and Mathematica says the solution is
$$f(x) = \dfrac{b^{\log_a x}}{b}$$
but I'm stumped about how one might prove that. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's often the case that, having found one good solution by whatever means, you can prove that it's unique (or unique up to a constant or some such simple factor).  Here, given your special solution $f_0(x)$.  Maybe look at the function $H(x)=\frac {f(x)}{f_0(x)}$.

Comment: There would also be the solution $f(x)=0$ and you can generalize your solution to $f(x)=\text{c}\cdot b^{\log_{a}(x)-1}$ with $\text{c}$ as an arbitrary complex constant. More general: If $f\left( x \right) = g\left( x \right)$ is a solution to $f\left( a \cdot x \right) = b \cdot f\left(x\right)$, then $f\left(x\right)=\text{c}\cdot g\left(x\right) \wedge \text{c} \in \mathbb{C}$ is also a solution to the same functional equation. You can prove your solution by substituting it into the equation and showing that it produces a true statement (both sides are equal).